# Zend_Controller_Request::setRedirect() does not seem to work?

Tags: zend-framework

i am not sure if calling setRedirect from the resource object is the best way. but i wonder why this does not seem to do anything. i have this in a predispatch controller plugin

```
function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $req) {
    ...
    if (!$acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $privilege)) {  
        ...
        $res = $this->_response;
        $res->setRedirect('/error/?error-handler=unauthorized', 403);
    }
}
```

if u prefer the whole code, get it @[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3PwtsJGb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setRedirect()` does not stop the dispatchloop from executing. To do the redirect you have to send the headers and exit the process.

```
$res->setRedirect('/error/?error-handler=unauthorized', 403);
$res->sendHeaders();
exit();
```

A better way would be to use the Redirector `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector')->gotoUrl()`